# The method 'debug_traceTransaction' does not exist / is not available. Remix in BSC test net

Tags: remix, bsc, pancakeswap

I deployed with Remix a contract on BSC testnet successfully.

I have tried to use the remix debugger with a failed transaction (swap in pancakeswap) but I get the following error message in Remix:

> The method 'debug_traceTransaction' does not exist / is not available.
> { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 2296864828, "method":
> "debug_traceTransaction", "params": [
> "0x59fb6c05cb39c27c72b20bf35b46bd2c60a0e4d1845d70e4e50230bd9bed951b",
> { "disableStorage": true, "disableMemory": false, "disableStack":
> false, "fullStorage": false } ], "origin":
> "https://remix.ethereum.org", "tabId": 426 }

Transaction: https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x59fb6c05cb39c27c72b20bf35b46bd2c60a0e4d1845d70e4e50230bd9bed951b

Comment: From the error message 'Pancake: TRANSFER_FAILED' a token transfer is failing. In order to debug remix needs the injected provider support debugging, public nodes usually don't support it because those methods are a resource hog.