# swapTokensForEth transaction fail when called within a contract in a swap

Tags: solidity, bsc, solidity-0.6.x

I have this token test contract: The contract has a transaction tax of 1%. The transaction fee is converted to (`myContractToken` to bnb) and sent to a wallet. It is used the balance of the token that the contract already had before the current transaction.

Transfer:

```
function _transfer(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 amount
) internal override {
    
    require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
    require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

    if(amount == 0) {
        super._transfer(from, to, 0);
        return;
    }


    bool takeFee = !swappingToBnb && !_isExcludedFromFees[from] && !_isExcludedFromFees[to];

     if(takeFee) {
    
        uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        
        if(contractTokenBalance>0)
        {
           sellForBNBAndSendToDev();
        }
        
        uint256 fees = amount.mul(devFee).div(100);
        amount = amount.sub(fees);
        super._transfer(from, address(this), fees);
        
    }

    super._transfer(from, to, amount);


}
```

sellForBNBAndSendToDev:

```
function sellForBNBAndSendToDev() public  {
    
    swappingToBnb = true;
    swapTokensForEth(balanceOf(address(this)));
    uint256 bnbToSend = address(this).balance;
    _devWallet.transfer(bnbToSend);
    swappingToBnb = false;
}
```

SwapTokensForEth:

```
function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {


    // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = address(this);
    path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();

    _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

    // make the swap
    uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        tokenAmount,
        0, // accept any amount of ETH
        path,
        address(this),
        block.timestamp
    );

}
```

-If I call with a wallet that is not excluded from the fee from the PancakeSwap interface the transaction fails (it is not slipage problem):

https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x1ca182c630a186d9f1f4b0d564d9de1703e694520e8eb0718b4dba68a6a78744

-If I delete call to `sellForBNBAndSendToDev();` the transaction does not fail

-If I call `sellForBNBAndSendToDev` directly, the transaction doesn't fail:

https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x1fb50a5c87ec05dc018a5ce87437a28c0bcf91800a0bf7e6005d307d946a3ba7

-If instead of using the PancakeSwap interface, I do a "normal" transaction by sending tokens from one wallet to another. `sellForBNBAndSendToDev()` runs without fail:

https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xce768de8dd9304845df1826a4e22f96200e3b6185db74aa62c9adc96dbc8db12

That is, `sellForBNBAndSendToDev ()` only fails when doing a swap with the PancaKswap interface.

On the other hand, I have tried to debug the transaction that fails, but I can't because I get this error: [The method 'debug_traceTransaction' does not exist / is not available. Remix in BSC test net](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/109574/the-method-debug-tracetransaction-does-not-exist-is-) not-available-remix-in

---------New test----------

I have used [this tool](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/bsc-testnet/0xb763a741127ea31b86098ba8b43036a4d79dcd32d84e45c1057e4f67ef4c97b5) to debug failed transaction:

The problem is in

"sellForBNBAndSendToDev" -> "swapTokensForEth" -> "swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens" -> "pair.swap"

[image]

inside PancakeSwap lib.

Although it is useful information, I do not know what the problem is.

Comment: Does it throw error before sending transaction or not?! Also, is there liquidity or not?!

Comment: Before sending the transaction, PancakeSwap locks the transaction. It tells me that a problem has occurred with the tokens and does not send the transaction to the metamask. I have the failed transaction executed because I have used a "trick" to submit the transaction even though PancakeSwap knows in advance that it is going to fail. Yes token have liquidity.

Comment: What is the "trick"?!

Comment: The first transaction does not fail, because the contract does not yet have the tokens in the balance. Therefore, sellForBNBAndSendToDev() is not executed in the first transaction. The second transaction "if (contractTokenBalance> 0)" is the one that fails. Therefore the "trick" so that the PancekeSwap interface does not stop the second transaction is to send the two transactions at the same time in a period of 1-3 seconds. If I wait a little longer, PancakeSwap will notice and stop the second transaction before it fails.

Comment: Why don't you dedicate some initial balance to the contract?! So it fails even it has balance?!

Comment: Whenever there is balance in the contract, it fails. In other words, whenever "sellForBNBAndSendToDev" is executed (because the contract has a balance) and it is a PancekeSwap swap it fails. Therefore the problem is in "sellForBNBAndSendToDev". I have tried in tests and run the function "sellForBNBAndSendToDev" in isolation and there are no problems.

Comment: What is the output of the `swapTokensForEth` function when you try directly?! WBNB or BNB?!

Comment: BNB. https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xce768de8dd9304845df1826a4e22f96200e3b6185db74aa62c9adc96dbc8db12 --> "(TRANSFER  0.00000000000000998 BNB From 0xae...To  0x9..)"

Comment: So, one problem found! It is not BNB, it is WBNB! You must change WBNB into BNB before calling`uint256 bnbToSend = address(this).balance; _devWallet.transfer(bnbToSend);`

Comment: I'm going to try wbnb. But I don't think that's the problem because I have copied those lines of code from a token that is in production. Furthermore, this function works correctly when it is called from a transaction between two normal wallets. But I'm going to test if this is the problem. You can check here in last transactions that is working: https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xce768de8dd9304845df1826a4e22f96200e3b6185db74aa62c9adc96dbc8db12#internal

Answer (score 0):

I have been analyzing the code of other tokens in production that use the call to "swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens" during a transaction. I have found a pattern, all tokens only use this call in sells, that is, when the contract token is "sold" for BNB.

I have verified that this problem does not occur in sells. Therefore I have added an if so that it only executes "swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens" on sells transactions and the problem does not occur.

Comment: Hello.... were you able to fix the problem? Could you share the code fixed? I am having this same problem even if I am swaping only for transaction from uniswapV2Router.